# Understanding IL generated of the following snippet

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

Hello i am trying to use `Reflection.Emit` to generate a method dynamically and i do not know how to interpret the following snippet:

**C#**  (What i want to generate)

```
 public Task<Cell> GetAsync(string key)
{
    IEnumerable<Component<Cell>> async = Core.ComponentEnumerator.Instance.GetAsync(key);
    Command<Cell> command = new Command<Cell>(async);
    return this.ProcessAsync<Cell>(command);
}
```

**IL** generated in release mode

```
method public hidebysig newslot virtual final instance class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<valuetype redius.Cell> GetAsync(string key) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<valuetype redius.Component`1<valuetype redius.Cell>> enumerable,
        [1] valuetype redius.Command`1<valuetype redius.Cell> command)
    L_0000: call class redius.Core/ComponentEnumerator redius.Core/ComponentEnumerator::get_Instance()
    L_0005: ldarg.1 
    L_0006: callvirt instance class [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<valuetype redius.Component`1<valuetype redius.Cell>> redius.Core/ComponentEnumerator::GetAsync(string)
    L_000b: stloc.0 
    L_000c: ldloca.s command
    L_000e: ldloc.0 
    L_000f: call instance void redius.Command`1<valuetype redius.Cell>::.ctor(class [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<valuetype redius.Component`1<!0>>)
    L_0014: ldarg.0 
    L_0015: ldloc.1 
    L_0016: call instance class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> redius.OpsGenTemplate::ProcessAsync<valuetype redius.Cell>(valuetype redius.Command`1<!!0>)
    L_001b: ret 
}
```

Can someone please explain to me the following points:

**1** The first instruction `L_0000` calls a singleton object but does not store its value anywhere.Why does it  not use `ldarg.0` and then forward this value into the  `Command<Cell>` constructor?.
**2** It then calls `ldarg.1`...when in our method we have only 1 argument of the method.

I was expecting something along the lines:

1.Load the argument 0 - `ldarg.0`
2.`stloc` it in  `async` variable 
3. call constructor of `Command<Cell>` that consumes the above line
4.`stloc` it in `command`
5. call `ProcessAsync<Cell>`
6.`ret`

Comment: Instance methods have a hidden extra argument.  Passed first, it is `this` in your C# code.  It doesn't have to be stored, since it is already on the stack, all that is needed is to load the 2nd argument before calling GetAsync().  That load is ldarg_1 because your method is an instance method as well.  Make this method *static* to see the code generation change.  It should be static since it doesn't use any fields of the enclosing class.